# Visual studio and MS build have different build results

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Lately we (the team I work with and myself) have been seeing something strange between the build results of MS-build and Visual Studio (2015).

### The situation

The team I work with has been tasked with refactoring an older and rather large c# project that contains many (150+) projects all bundled into a single sln file. As to be expected merge conflicts occur in the sln file during our work and one of the team members resolved this conflict incorrectly. Leaving the sln file with a **missing project reference**.

From here on out the behavior of the project is different on 3 location. They are described below

---

#### Visual studio of the developer that origionally made the mistake

(note that I assume that this developer has *not* cleaned his solution)
This programmer has already build and run the project (using visual studio 2015 professional). So all compiled dll files are in the prorammers output folder. This means that Visual studio does not notice that a reference is missing. The programmer can build, run and test the application without any problems.

---

#### The build server

The build server (Jenkins) does not run Visual studio, but it uses MS-build 14 to compile the source code. The Jenkins server is configured to run with pipelines, described in groovy. We call ms build by invoking a bat script that runs MS-build over the command line. An example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe" "TheSolutionFile.sln" /property:Configuration="Debug" /property:Platform="Any CPU"
```

Somehow the build will succeed even with the incorrect sln file. I suspect that ms build resolves its own dependencies as the workspace on the buildserver is clean (completely empty) so no leftover dll's can fool the system. *(am I correct in assuming this?)*

---

#### The other team members

The other team members will eventually pull the changes of the broken sln file and they will be in for some 'fun'. When you do not have the dll files in your output folder Visual studio will attempt to rebuild the missing dependencies. But since the references cannot be resolved it will fail and start stacking errors about missing meta data. In the team we all use Visual studio 2015. But we also tried it with 2017 and ran into the same result. The person who originally made the mistake can also end up in this group of he cleans the solution.

### The Question

Obviously we are not happy with the fact that the build server accepts the build with a broken sln file (a developer pulling the latest version cannot compile or run the program). **Is there a way to get the last two situations in sync (so ms build not accepting a 'broken' sln file to compile)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the last two situations in sync (so ms build not accepting a 'broken' sln file to compile

That is because MSBuild.exe from command line **does not** have the same build environment as Visual Studio. You can call MSBuild.exe from [VS command promt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859.aspx) which has the same biuld environment as Visual Studio.

If you want call ms build by invoking a bat script that runs MS-build over the command line, you can use **devenv.exe to build the solution/project from command line**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>devenv "D:\TestSample\TestProject\TestProject\TestProject.sln" /build Debug /project "TestProject\TestProject.csproj" /projectconfig Debug
```

For the detail information about devenv.exe you can refer to [Devenv Command Line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Would this require me to have Visual studio installed on the build node or is there a 'standalone' version for devenv?

Comment: @NickOtten, Yes, as far as I know you need to install Visual Studio on the build server.

Comment: Hmm not what I had hoped for. But I guess that is the way to go then. Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 0):

My advice:

The .sln file is just a collection of project files.  Create a brand new one, and add in your proj files one by one.  Forget the code-merge-conflict-resolution drama.

The voodoo in the .sln file is too much voodoo.  Let VS do it for you...as you add each project in, one by one.

> File / New / Project ::: Installed / Templates / Other Project Types / Visual Studio Solution ::: Blank
>   Solution.

One other hint.  If you still have issues, then open up each proj, and any "**by project**" references, delete them and re-add them.  Sometimes the GUID's get mixed up, especially over a long code-merge history.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the hints! Unfortunately this does not fully resolve the problem I have. Getting the sln file to work again is doable. The main Issue I have is that the build server is not detecting when a sln file is flawed. If I pull a version of the code it could completely fail the compile step in VS because of the broken sln file. But if I where to compile that same code in ms build using the command line, it works fine.